# How to install only single component instead of whole package?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, warnings, material-ui, alert

**BACKGROUND:**

Hello I am new to react development and currently developing a web application using material ui and I want to display error and success messages, I want to use "mdbalert" from mdbreact. (I am aware of snackbar but I find it confusing)

**PROBLEM:**

How do I install only ***mdbalert*** instead of installing whole **mdbreact** package.

Any suggestion or hint would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you would install the entire package. Then only import the mdbreact as you require it.

To require just a part of the mbreact component, you would do it like this:

```
import React from "react"; // import react and other modules
import { MDBContainer, MDBAlert } from 'mdbreact'; // import MDBAlert and other components of mbreact
```

When it comes to production mode, Webpack should compile only the code that has been imported (in this case MDBAlert) and not the entire mbreact module.